# How can I bind data from the API in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm new in React.JS. I want to bind data from the API in a HTML code.
Here is a `GET` method with axios from the API:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    var config = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + token }
    };
    var apiBaseUrl = "https://**********/";
    const that = this;
    axios.get(apiBaseUrl + 'api/Account/UserInfo', config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                that.setState({ userInfo: response.data });
                console.log(that.state.userInfo.Email);
            }
            else {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

The console shows me

> `{Email: "xxxxxxx@yahoo.com", HasRegistered: true, LoginProvider: null}`

Now I want to display the email address in HTML. How can I do this?

Comment: just use state value to in html like `<div>{this.state.userInfo.Email}</div>`. If you get Email of undefined then try `{this.state.userInfo && <div>{this.state.userInfo.Email}</div>}`

Comment: you have an error in your code `that.setState({ userInfo: response.data });` We use this not that

Answer (score 2):

Here you've set the state

```
 that.setState({ userInfo: response.data });
```

To access it - try `this.state.userInfo.Email`

You can put that into some html elements like this

```
<p>{this.state.userInfo.Email}</p>
```

Comment: show this error for all solution
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userInfo' of null

Answer (score 1):

In JSX you can show like this

```
render(){
  return (
    <p>{this.state.userInfo ? this.state.userInfo.Email : 'Email is not provided'}</p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in JSX you just define

```
render(){
const email = this.state.userInfo? this.state.userInfo.Email:'';
return(
  <div>{email}</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: show this error for all solution
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userInfo' of null

Comment: @mobinakhalilzade check now